# How do I remove a folder from Windows Distributed File System?

Tags: filesystems, microsoft-distributed-file-system

We recently moved to a webfarm and setup dfs, only to find a beta application was creating files like there was no tomorrow. 1.2 million files were replicated across the farm, and since then we have prevented the application from creating new files, but every time we try to remove the files, it replaces them on each server because of replication. The process of replacing them actually causes to server to run slowly and in some cases stall.

Is there any way we can stop replication at a folder level?

Answer (score 1):

Then I guess something in your setup is fishy, as the FRS also replicates deletes accross servers